# doctrine2 - entity is member of

Tags: php, mysql, doctrine-orm

for the sake of example:

i have the following schema:

```
users(id, name)
groups(id,name)
user_groups(user_id, group_id)
```

i want to fetch users that belong to a certain group. problem is, i know the group id, so i don't want to join the groups table - user_groups is sufficient.

the result should be

```
SELECT * FROM `users` AS u
LEFT JOIN `user_groups` AS ug ON (ug.`user_id` = u.`id)
WHERE ug.`group_id` = X
// i know the value of X
```

my attempts in doctrine2 resulted in another join of the `groups` table.

the closest thing i got is:

```
SELECT u FROM models\User u WHERE ?1 MEMBER OF u.groups
```

but it will also LEFT JOIN it inside the "WHERE EXISTS(...)"

can this be done without native query (using DQL/query builder)?

Answer (score 3):

One of the advantages of ORM over ActiveRecord pattern is that, you don't need to create a new entity for join tables.

So here when you use Doctrine, the `user_groups` table will be mapped on both sides.

That means you cannot access the user_groups table directly. Unless you use native sql, which i strongly advice against.

So the best way to tackle your situation is to use `findOneBy($group_id)` on group repo and get the users from it. That the theoretically correct way to implement it.

-- EDIT -- 
For your comment:

yes, i agree that from the pure db POV its more efficient.

But you won't be able to do it without native query as DQL, query builder and everything related to doctrine uses Entities to perform action and since you are using an ORM by design, you won't have an entity for Join tables.

Else the only way is to change your mapping from `a many to many relation from user to groups using join table` to `a one-to-many from users to user_groups and a many-to-one from user_groups to groups`. That way you will have an entity for `user_groups`.

Then you can directly use that entity to get the users.

Even though its a hack, its not technically & theoretically correct to use like that. Unless of course the join table has other responsibilities also.

Comment: but that will result in 2 queries. my current technique which only adds a left join will run in 1 query. my current approach is more efficient.

Comment: the answer is too big for the comment, so please check my ans above. :)

Comment: in this case you can "fetch a group, and the request for the group's users", or "fetch all users that belong to a group". i'm doing the latter - both are correct (entity wise). all i'm saying (or asking), is that the ORM should be implemented in a way that queries are optimized and only the necessary data is handled. it's not a question of theoretically correctness (since both ways are correct), but a question regarding the implementation efficiency of the ORM (only use what you need to use). anyhow, thanks for the input ;)

Comment: @galchen - the overhead of the additional join is so incredibly negligible, considering that it's essentially just a PK lookup.

Comment: i didn't say it's not negligible. it is joining another table record using primary key. all i'm saying is that doctrine2 implementation should eventually skip that since it's not necessary. call it my little quest for perfection